# How to download doc file using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, download, doc

I got the following error while trying to download file using java-script.

**ERROR:**

```
Internet Explorer cannot download Sample.doc from www.websitename.com.

Internet Explorer was not able to open this Internet site. The request is either unavailable or cannot be found.Please try again later.
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
function winopen() 
{ 
  window.open("Sample.doc","_self","fullscreen=no,toolbar=yes, width=800, height=600, menubar=yes, status=no,scroll=yes"); 
} 
</script>
</head>
<body onload="winopen();">
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope it will help

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812935

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316431

Comment: @sukhi Your code is working in other browsers or not? i mean is it working in mozilla, opera or crome?

Comment: try _blank instead of _self and remove all spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the full, VALID URI for the resource you're trying to get to the `window.open` function. 
E.g. To download a stylesheet from the BBC website:

```
window.open("http://static.bbc.co.uk/homepage/css/bundles/domestic/main.css?661" "_self","fullscreen=no,toolbar=yes, width=800, height=600, menubar=yes, status=no,scroll=yes");
```

BTW there is no website at http://www.websitename.com  ;-)

HTH.